# Authorize Web API and 401 error

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, authentication, asp.net-web-api, authorization

I have a MVC and a Web API projects within the same solution, on the MVC project I have a very small Admin area protected with a login and password (just for one user). On this area I get the data on clinet side using API calls.

This is my Login function:

```
public ActionResult SubmitLogin(string UserName, string Password)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            if (UserName == "xxxxx" && Password == "yyyyy")
            {
                FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(UserName, true);
                return RedirectToAction("Index", @"Admin/Users");
            }
        }
        var errors = (from value in ModelState.Values
                      from error in value.Errors
                      select error.ErrorMessage).ToList();

        if (errors.Count == 0)
        {
            errors.Add("UserName or Password are incorrect");
        }

        ViewBag.Message = errors;
        return View("Index");
    }
```

The Login form works fine, the issue is with the API calls, my API controller is `[Authorize]` but when I make a request:

```
self.getUsers = function (callback) {
    $.get("../MySite.API/Users/GetUsers/", callback);
}
```

I get a 401 error.

I understand I have to somehow send the `AuthCookie` with the AJAX request but I'm not sure how.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Refer http://forum.jquery.com/topic/username-and-password-in-an-ajax-call. hope it helps you.

Comment: Did the link in Vinutha's comment help you?

Comment: @RuardvanElburg not really.